# React native no funciona

Tags: react-native

Tengo un problema con react native, creo nuevos proyectos y no me deja correrlos. El error ocurre directamente, solo creo el proyecto e inmediatamente lo ejecuto. Me aparece la pantalla roja con el siguiente error:

> Failed ot load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(/Users/React/Documents/nativeapps/CPH/index.js: invalid value for dynamic deps behavior: `null` (null))

[image: Pantalla de simulador ios 11.1 iPhone 5s]

Ignoro completamente que genera este error, es un proyecto nuevo, solo hago:

```
react-native init proyecto
react-native run-ios --simulator "iPhone 5s"
```

y solo me muestra el error, no cambio absolutamente nada en código. Es como si ya no funcionase react native.

Estoy usando react-native: 0.52.0 y react-native-cli: 2.0.1

Comment: Hola Sergio, ¿podrías agregar el código/ficheros de configuración que hacen que te salga este error? ¿qué pone en los logs? Creo que será más fácil ayudarte de ese modo. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información. Un saludo.

Comment: para serte franco ignoro completamente que genera este error, es un proyecto nuevo, solo hago: react-native init proyecto y despues react-native run-ios --simulator "iPhone 5s" y solo me muestra el error, no cambio absolutamente nada en codigo, no tengo idea de a que se deba

Comment: Bueno, intenta añadiendo más información: ¿qué versión de React Native usas? Parece que hay más [gente a la que le está dando este mismo error ahora mismo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347359/error-on-running-a-clean-react-native-project) (a no ser que seas Albertus también) después de actualizar a la última versión de React Native, así que podría ser un problema de compatibilidades con algo.

Comment: react-native: 0.52.0 y react-native-cli: 2.0.1

Comment: Esa es la misma versión que le da problemas a los otros. ¿Usas metro? Parece que la persona que publicó la pregunta en inglés, encontró la solución: es un problema con la versión de metro y haciendo `npm install metro` se solucionó su problema.

Comment: si uso metro, te doy los datos que me arroja react-native info:
Environment:
  OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.6
  Node: 8.9.1
  Yarn: 1.3.2
  npm: 5.6.0
  Watchman: 4.9.0
  Xcode: Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
  Android Studio: 3.0 AI-171.4443003

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.2.0 => 16.2.0
  react-native: 0.52.0 => 0.52.0

Comment: Prueba a correr `npm install metro`  como se sugiere en la otra respuesta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El error ha ocurrido por un fallo en la última versión de metro, como se indica en este [hilo de Github](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/126) (traducción mía):

> Lo siento muchachos, esto ha sido causado porque añadimos un nuevo parámetro de configuración para permitir requires dinámicos. PEro ese nuevo parámetro no se maneja en RN v0.52 y hace que metro falle.
>
> Voy a publicar la versión v0.24.6 para solucionarlo lo antes posible

Entonces la solución al problema es actualizar metro a la versión más moderna. Algo que puedes hacer utilizando el siguiente comando ([como se especifica en SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48347949/3695983)):

```
npm install metro
```

Comment: Funcionó!!! Muchas gracias!!!